# How to get merged project results in SonarQube from 2 scanners?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We are using the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild and the default SonarQube Scanner through Jenkins in our project. The two scanners are executed from different jenkins jobs. One job for .net code and the default scanner for java & typescript.

As project version, the git commit hash is used. The results from both scanners seem to overwrite each other even with the same commit hash. 
Either we have only C# results or only java / ts results.

How can we get merged results in one SQ project?

SonarQube Version 5.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just impossible to merge analysis reports for one project.

Technically, this would probably be achievable to execute only 1 single SonarQube analysis that does both the .NET part and the Java/JavaScript part. This would answer your use case. But this would be a kind of hack.

IMO, the good way to do it is to split your source code in 2: the .NET part and the Java part. There are chances that these are 2 different technical components anyway, that might have different life cycles even though they relate to the same "business" application.